# Programmatically start edit mode in TurboTable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Currently TurboTable in PrimeNG has ability to enable edit mode by adding `pEditableColumn` directive into table cell and using `p-cellEditor` to create suitable template for preview and edit view.

By default, only way to enter edit mode is single click. Is there any option to start edit mode programmatically ?

I want to change behaviour of edit mode - I want to start edit mode by double click, not single click.

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a way to change this to work on double click instead of single click